# factor models and using cross section regression

Tags: statistics, portfolio-management, factor-models, portfolio-optimization

I have been doing some reading on factor models. In the literature it mentions that when creating a portfolio that maximises particular attributes it may lead to unwanted bias to other factors. I understand this part.

So they create 'true' factor scores which clean a factor of the influences of all the other factors. It mentions the use of cross-sectional regressions to simultaneously remove these side effects. It is this part I am unsure of. I do not know how they are 'cleaning' their factors and if this is a standard practise?

**further information**

A variable is decomposed into the true variable and the parts that are shared with other common variables. This is done using the residual variable methodology.

Comment: Which literature are you referring to? Can you give any references?

Comment: its a presentation I have been forwarded by a client. I would normally ask them however the author is away on holiday for the next two weeks. Sadly I cannot give any references. I have edited my post and added some further information although there isn't a huge amount to add.

Comment: Speaking from equity quant factor building experience, it is a common practice to build multi-factor models by regressing one component against other(s) and using the residual scores. This is done to avoid bias as you mentioned - these biases could be from the factor itself (in different regimes, Quality / Momentum influencing each other - or earnings, value bringing opposite extremes to the portfolio ranking etc.). Robeco have done a few papers on regressed residual factors (mostly momentum ). one of the papers can be found here.
http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1911449

Comment: @Viquar thanks for the comment. Have just downloaded the paper which I am about to go over. So if there was a momentum factor they would regress this on the other factors. The residual from this regression is that the 'true' part of the momentum factor?

Comment: Indeed. let's say you have a pool of factors which you believe may have crossover information. the goal is to strip the factors of this linked information and therefore using regressed residuals as clean factor scores.

Comment: great thanks for you help. If you put your comment and link as an answer I will that as the correct answer.

Comment: @Viquar I'm more familiar with the approach in that paper as applied to momentum than I am with respect to characteristics-based factors (e.g. P/E). In a cross-sectional approach (as in Barra), one can use a GLS approach to account for the correlation between factors, though I'm not sure how important it is for the level of coefficients versus standard errors.

Comment: It is an immensely popular / common approach (and commercially successful too as the good folks at Barra would tell you). Of course, I do find while on one hand it's easy to generalize, on the other hand, it's very difficult to have a one-glove-fits-all kind of approach. For most fund managers, assessing portfolio risk cross-sectionally makes far greater sense to estimate portfolio [incidental or otherwise] biases and exposures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking from equity quant factor building experience, it is a common practice to build multi-factor models by regressing one component against other(s) and using the residual scores. This is done to avoid bias as you mentioned - these biases could be from the factor itself (in different regimes, Quality / Momentum influencing each other - or earnings, value bringing opposite extremes to the portfolio ranking etc.).

Robeco have done a few papers on regressed residual factors (mostly momentum), such as ["Short-Term Residual Reversal"](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1911449).